# Error executing PowerShell.Invoke method on Current Application Pool Uptime performance counter

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, performancecounter

Good morning.

In PowerShell, Windows 10 executed the following command for performance counter **Current Application Pool Uptime**:

```
 Get-Counter -Counter '\\khubetsov-pc\APP_POOL_WAS(DefaultAppPool)\Current Application Pool Uptime'
```

Result of command executed:
[image]

Next, using C # (Net Framework 4.8), I want to get the results of the PowerShell command above:

```
var ps = PowerShell.Create();

var command = new Command(@"Get-Counter", isScript: false);

var commandParameter = new CommandParameter("Counter", @"\\khubetsov-pc\APP_POOL_WAS(DefaultAppPool)\Current Application Pool Uptime");
command.Parameters.Add(commandParameter);

ps.Commands.AddCommand(command);

var result = ps.Invoke();
```

However, there is no data in the result variable, the **HadErrors** property of the **PowerShell** class instance has a value of **True** and the following error text is set: **The specified counter was not found**.

**Questions:**

1. As I understood, the error is related to specifying an incorrect value for the performance counter path;
2. How do I correctly convey the meaning of a path if any recommendations or rules;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was found that when passing the name of the counter in the current language (in this case, Russian), everything works. Below is a special service:

```
public static class PerformanceCounterService
{

    private static (string Russian, string English) _performanceCounterName = ("текущее время работы пула приложений", "current application pool uptime");

    public static float NextValueExt(PerformanceCounter performanceCounter)
    {
        if (performanceCounter == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(performanceCounter));

        if (performanceCounter.CounterName.ToLower() == _performanceCounterName.English)
        {
            var separator = @"\";
            var instance = string.IsNullOrEmpty(performanceCounter.InstanceName) ? string.Empty : $"({performanceCounter.InstanceName})";
            var counterName = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name == CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US").Name ? _performanceCounterName.English : _performanceCounterName.Russian;
            var path = string.Concat(separator, performanceCounter.CategoryName, instance, separator, counterName);
            var computerName = string.Empty;

            if (performanceCounter.MachineName != ".")
            {
                computerName = $"-ComputerName '{performanceCounter.MachineName}'";
            }

            var script = $"(Get-Counter -Counter '{path}' {computerName}).CounterSamples";

            var ps = PowerShell.Create()
                               .AddScript(script);

            var iResult = ps.Invoke();

            if (!ps.HadErrors)
            {
                var psObject = iResult.FirstOrDefault()?.Members["CookedValue"]?.Value ?? default;

                return Convert.ToSingle(psObject);
            }
        }

        return performanceCounter.NextValue();
    }
}
```